# Как элементы ul, div научить нормально получать и терять фокус?

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

Даётся фокус списку

```
jQuery("dl",list).focus();
```

Всё как бы хорошож событие `.on("focus")` срабатывает, а вот событие потери фокуса не срабатывает.

```
jQuery("dl", list).on("focusout",hideDropDown);
```

Фокус добавляется, когда открываешь кастомный `select`, IE7 - IE8

Подскажите, пожалуйста, причину.

Comment: А каким образом DL может получить фокус? Он ведь не является активным элементом. В зависимости от того, что вам нужно, смотрите в сторону click, mouseenter, keydown и проч.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для ul, div используется [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) и [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)

Если нужно свелосипедить фокус для блочных элементов (div, p, li ...), то при помощи [keydown](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) можно отследить клавишу TAB или SHIFT+TAB и дальше добавлять класс "focus" нужным элементам.